# Set property to generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have two classes `Car` and `Truck`, and they both extend my `Vehicle` class. Both `Car` and `Truck` have property that looks like this:

```
public int Wheels { get; set; }
```

Now, I have two methods which set the `Wheels` property to some variable. It looks like this:

```
public void SetCarWheels(int value)
{
     Car.Wheels = value;
}

public void SetTruckWheels(int value)
{
     Truck.Wheels = value;
}
```

Because the methods do the same thing, I wanted to make a method which would have an input parameter of type `Vehicle`. The method should basically do this:

```
public static void SetWheels<T>(Vehicle item, int wheels) where T : Vehicle
    {
        if (item!= null)
        {
            item.Wheels = wheels;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, it doesn't recognize the `Wheels` property.

How can I solve this by using generics?

Please don't suggest alternative solutions without generics (I know that `Car` and `Truck` can have a const value of wheels, but for the sake of the problem let's leave this as it is).

Comment: What type is `previouslySelectedItem`? Why `SetWheels` is generic? You don't use the `T` anywhere in code.

Comment: Where and how are you declaring the previouslySelectedItem object?

Comment: seems messy - for example what is `previouslySelectedItem`? - You don't use `T` nor `item` in your `SetWheels` and the `Wheels` property has an public setter anyway ....

Comment: @pwas I changed the code, sorry.

Comment: @CarstenKönig  I changed the code, sorry.

Comment: @NahuelI. I changed the code, sorry.

Comment: is this property static or not?

Comment: @CarstenKönig It's not static.

Comment: ok then you SetCarWheels are wrong - go with the provided answer or use `if (item is Car) ((Car)item).Wheels = ...` (of course you can also use `typeOf` or whatever you like to decide the instance at runtime - you will just not get a static checked code this way)

Comment: Or... `((dynamic)item).Wheels = ...`. This is one of the way, but I wouldn't recommend it to you. It can cause many problems at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will only work if the property is an instance property in the `Vehicle` base class:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in your method you don't seem to use the generic type parameter and the variable:

```
public static void SetWheels<T>(T item, int wheels) where T : Vehicle
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Wheels = wheels;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so - it seems that the property is static even if he did not say so - and of course the code can work if he just checks the provided types (lame dynamic dispatch)

Comment: That is possible indeed. That's why it should be a instance variable on `Vehicle` like in my code.

Comment: @CarstenKönig I think `Car` and `Truck` both have the property `Wheels`, but its baseclass `Vehicle` doesnt.

Comment: If both `Car` and `Truck` have the (independent) property `Wheels`, but `Vehicle` doesn't, then the question is: *why?* - If `Vehicle` absolutely must not have the `Wheels` property, then `Car` and `Truck` could implement an interface like `ISettableWheels { void SetWheels(int wheels); }`

Comment: Or maybe an intermediate class: `Vehicle` <- `VehicleWithWheels` <- [`Car`, `Truck`]

Comment: @CarstenKönig: It is possible (though confusing) that both `Car` and `Truck` in the code are variable names that are the same as their class name.

Comment: With assume, that OP can modyify the classes (maybe they are stored in some api).

Comment: @pwas: If he has implemented `Car` and `Truck` he probably too implemented `Vehicle`. From question: " they both extend *my* Vehicle class"